# .gitignore is not ignoring my vim temporary files

Tags: git, vim

I'm having issues with my .gitignore file. I have done my research and have tried many methods. The steps below happen when I save my .gitignore

```
git rm -rf --cached *.php.*
git add .
git status
git commmit -m "some message"
```

Here's is what my .gitignore file looks like:

```
# Ignores anything that's a temp file created by vim
.*.s??
.*.*.s??
```

Here are the files it should be keeping from being tracked

```
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       .ajax.php.swn
#       .ajax.php.swo
#       .ajax.php.swp
#       .swervepay.php.swn
#       .swervepay.php.swo
#       .swervepay.php.swp
#       .swervepay_form.php.swm
#       .swervepay_form.php.swn
#       .swervepay_form.php.swp
```

What can I do to keep these files from gettin tracked? Everytime I do a git add . and commit to push up, those files get re-added. Any help would be greatful.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your configuration, but even a simple `*.sw?` should work (no leading dot needed). Maybe `.gitignore` is in the wrong place.

Comment: The .gitignore will work when I add the full filename so it's not that it's in the wrong place. It'll work if I list the filenames in full. I just ended up creating a global file and removed the sw* files from the directory. Hopefully after that commit if anything gets added it will be ignored.

Answer (score 28):

### Use standard rules

There's [a handy repository on github for ignore rules](https://github.com/github/gitignore/), for [Vim the rules are](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Vim.gitignore):

```
# swap
[._]*.s[a-w][a-z]
[._]s[a-w][a-z]
# session
Session.vim
# temporary
.netrwhist
*~
# auto-generated tag files
tags
```

The best way to make use of rules like this are to [put them in your global git ignore file](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files):

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore
```

### Or put your swap files somewhere else

However it's probably a better idea to do this:

```
" ~/.vimrc file

" swap files (.swp) in a common location
" // means use the file's full path
set dir=~/.vim/_swap//

" backup files (~) in a common location if possible
set backup
set backupdir=~/.vim/_backup/,~/tmp,.

" turn on undo files, put them in a common location
set undofile
set undodir=~/.vim/_undo/
```

In this way vim won't be polluting your working copies with files, ignored or not =).

Comment: I'm taking this advice because just removing the temp files from that directory would be helpful in general. Thanks!

Comment: How do I check if the global configuration is working? A `git status` still shows the temporary files (ending with a tilde).

Comment: @Carcamano if you mean the standard git ignore file - if you're seeing those entries it's _not_ working investigate along the lines of: you aren't loading `~/.gitignore`. If you mean vim config, changing the config won't delete existing swap/tmp files.